# slow retrieval of BYTEA column

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm supposed to be testing different methods to store PDF files in a Postgres Database using JDBC. Currently I'm trying it with BYTEA. Storing files works without problems, but the retrieval is super slow.

I am working with a couple files around 3MB each. Storing them takes around 3 seconds (total), so that's alright. But when I try to retreive them, it takes around 2 minutes between the output of how many files are in the DB and the program actually starting to create the files. Once it starts, it only takes around 5 seconds though to finish. Why is Postgres taking so long for the Query "SELECT file..." ? The query takes equally long when I use pgAdmin. Not retrieving the filesize doesn't change anything.

As far as I understand, the DB uses TOAST to split my files up and when I want to retrieve them, it hast to piece them back together first. But since splitting them (when uploading) only takes a couple seconds, putting them back together shouldn't take that long, right?

Here are some code snippets:

```
public void saveToDB(Files[] files) {
    try (PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO fileTable (filename, file) VALUES (?,?)")) {
        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.println(f.getName()+" (" + f.length() / 1024 + "KB)");
            s.setString(1, f.getName());
            s.setBinaryStream(2, new FileInputStream(f), f.length());
            s.executeUpdate();
        }
        con.commit();
    }
}
public void getFromDB(File dir) {
    dir.mkdirs();
    try (Statement s = con.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM useByteA")) {
         rs.next();
         System.out.println("Files: " + rs.getInt(1));
    }
    try (Statement s = con.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT length(file), filename, file FROM fileTable")) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2)+" (" + rs.getInt(1) / 1024 + "KB)");
            File f = new File(dir, filename);
            f.createNewFile();
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                out.write(rs.getBytes(3));
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By default the Postgres JDBC driver buffers the **entire** result in memory before it returns the `ResultSet` back to the calling program. My guess is that this is what you are seeing. See the manual on how to configure the driver to *not* buffer the entire result: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: Wow, that's way too slow to make sense. Are you connecting over a super-slow network? It should be taking tens or hundreds of milliseconds for a 3MB file. Also, `TOAST` doesn't split the file up; you're thinking of `pg_largeobject` storage.

Comment: The DB is in my local network and storing files takes only a couple of seconds (for several files each around 3MB), so I don't think that the network is an issue.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Even if I add a "WHERE id=1" to the statement, thus only fetching a single file, it takes forever for Postgres to handle the request (no matter if with JDBC or pgAdmin).